# Thymeleaf + Spring: Getting extra line breaks when a template is parsed

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using .txt template in thmeleaf mentioned below:

```
Lorem ipsum
    [# th:if="${val}"]
    Do something
    [/]
    [# th:unless="${val}"]
    Do something else
    [/]
```

When parsing the above template using thymeleaf, after lorem ipsum if `{val}` is true, the output generated has an extra blank line below Lorem ipsum and if false there are two blank lines. I want no line below Lorem ipsum i.e out put should be in case of `{val}` being true:

```
Lorem ipsum
Do something
```

instead of

```
Lorem ipsum

Do something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thymeleaf isn't generating extra newlines -- the text in your template contains all the newlines that are being output (`\n` characters added for effect):

```
Lorem ipsum\n
[# th:if="${val}"]\n
Do something\n
[/]\n
[# th:unless="${val}"]\n
Do something else\n
[/]
```

If you don't want the newlines, you can't leave extra newlines in it to begin with.

```
Lorem ipsum
[# th:if="${val}"]Do something[/][# th:unless="${val}"]Do something else[/]
```

Or possibly

```
Lorem ipsum
[# th:text="${val ? 'Do something' : 'Do something else'}" /]
```